# Do the Jedi and Sith Temples lie along or at points of concentrated Force?

Tags: star-wars

I ask this because someone mentioned the possibility of Force Ley lines running through planets. I haven't read a lot of the books so maybe Ley lines are mentioned in a book. Or are Temples placement not that special?

Comment: Uh... Just to be clear. I was the one who mentioned Force Ley lines, and it was intended as a **totally unsubnstantiated theory**. To the best of my knowledge, in canon, there are no Force Ley Lines - I just made up a term (now watch Richard go and find one to my great embarassment :)

Comment: I like your theory! I was just trying to see if there were others out there that had the same idea.  No slight intended!

Comment: Just wanted to make sure I didn't inadvertently mislead you :). As far as Jedi Temples - I think *some* had some sort of specific meaning to their placement (check the Wookiepedia page for Jedi Temples, i seem to recall it mentioning that).

Answer (score 5):

### Canonical:

Although I don't know of any canon evidence that the temples are intentionally located on points that are stronger in the Force, it is clear that a temple's location can have enormous consequences.  The Jedi Temple on Coruscant was built atop an ancient Sith shrine, and this fact played a part in the downfall of the Jedi Order.  After Palpatine destroyed the Jedi and became Emperor, he turned the Coruscant temple into his royal palace, and used the Sith shrine as his "lair":

> The two of them [Sidious and his droid, 11-4D] were in Sidious’s lair, **a small rock-walled enclosure beneath the deepest of the Palace’s several sublevels that had once been an ancient Sith shrine. That the Jedi had raised their Temple over the shrine had for a thousand years been one of the most closely guarded secrets of those Sith Lords who had perpetuated and implemented the revenge strategy of the Jedi Order’s founders.** Even the most powerful of Dark Side Adepts believed that shrines of the sort existed only on Sith worlds remote from Coruscant, and **even the most powerful of the Jedi believed that the power inherent in the shrine had been neutralized and successfully capped. In truth, that power had seeped upward and outward since its entombment, infiltrating the hallways and rooms above, and weakening the Jedi Order much as the Sith Masters themselves had secretly infiltrated the corridors of political power and toppled the Republic.**
>
> Save for Sidious, no sentient being in close to five thousand years had set foot in the shrine. The room’s excavation and restoration had been carried out by machines under the supervision of 11-4D. **Even Vader was unaware of the shrine’s existence. But it was here that they would one day work together the way Sidious and Plagueis had to coax from the dark side its final secrets.** ...Success would grant them the power to harness the full powers of the dark side, and allow them to rule for ten thousand years.
>   -  *Star Wars:  Tarkin*

The author of *Tarkin*, James Luceno, continues:

> The Jedi tried to cap the power of this shrine, but there's leakage. It’s not just Sidious; it's the power of history, it's the residue of what's left of the dark side there.
>   - [James Luceno](http://star-wars.suvudu.com/2014/11/interview-with-james-luceno-author-star-wars-tarkin.html)

<sub>*Note:  According to Wookieepedia (referencing "[The Untold Clone Wars Panel Liveblog](http://www.starwars.com/news/swca-the-untold-clone-wars-panel-liveblog)", a more loosely described but similar concept was conceived of by George Lucas and* Clone Wars *creator Dave Filoni for the* Clone Wars *television show, but the series was cancelled before it could be introduced:*</sub>

> <sub>The idea of the Jedi Temple being built atop ancient temples would have been explored in the television series Star Wars: The Clone Wars, but the show was cancelled before such episodes could have been produced or released. **Series director Dave Filoni and creator George Lucas decided that the Jedi Temple had been built over ruins from ancient worshippers of the Force, possibly including the Sith.**</sub>

And in the canonical novel *Star Wars - Journey to the Force Awakens:  The Weapon of a Jedi*, Luke finds a ruined Jedi Temple on Devaron, in a location where the Force is quite strong:

> “**This place is strong with the Force**,” Ben Kenobi said in Luke’s head. “It was the will of the Force that guided you to this place. Here you will learn to open yourself to the Force, guiding its possibilities and obeying its commands. And passing its tests. May the Force be with you, Luke.”
>
> “Ben!” Luke called, but the voice of his old teacher was silent.
>
> Luke sat down on the rim of the fountain, in one of the long shadows the statues cast across the glen. **He could feel the power around him — power and a sense of peace**. This was the place the Force had shown him, and where it had brought him.

---

### Noncanonical:

From Wookieepedia's ["Behind the Scenes" section of the page for "Sith Shrine"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith_shrine#Behind_the_scenes):

> **The concept of the Jedi Temple being built over a wellspring of dark side energy was previously introduced in the continuity of Star Wars Legends.**

This sentence is linked, via a citation, to the Wookieepedia page for the Legends novel *[The New Jedi Order:  Traitor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_New_Jedi_Order:_Traitor)*:

> "**The dark side?**"
>
> "**It's... it's too strong for me here**. I warned you. I warned you
>   what could happen..." She raised her hand once more, reaching for his
>   leg; he took a hasty step back to avoid her touch, and she let her arm
>   fall limp to the floor.
>
> "You see..." she whispered, "...but you do not see. Jacen... **why
>   would the Jedi Council... build its Temple upon... a nexus of the dark
>   side?**"
>   -  *Star Wars:  The New Jedi Order:  Traitor*

The idea that the Jedi Temple on Coruscant was situated at a [nexus](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_nexus) of the Force is apparently [common](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Temple) in Legends (noncanonical) [material](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_New_Jedi_Order:_Enemy_Lines_II:_Rebel_Stand), but I'm not aware of any canon appearances of the concept apart from the aforementioned *Tarkin*.  In typical Wookieepedia fashion, the page on "Force Nexus" claims that the idea of force nexuses appears in each of the prequel trilogy films, as well as *The Empire Strikes Back*<sup>1</sup>, but doesn't say where or in what form the idea appears, and the entire page contains only one direct inline citation - to the noncanonical book [*The New Jedi Order: Enemy Lines II: Rebel Stand*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_New_Jedi_Order:_Enemy_Lines_II:_Rebel_Stand).

---

<sup>1</sup> *The ESB "appearance" is almost certainly supposed to be the "dark side cave" on Dagobah*