# Are there any blueprints of the Coruscant Jedi temple?

Tags: star-wars

By blueprint I mean architectural blueprint: something with entrances, exits, and the famous long corridors.

I checked Wookpedia and didn't find anything other than movie stills and concept sketches.

Comment: If you're also interested in written descriptions of it, the novel *Tarkin* has a lot of insight into the origins of the temple and it's structure, as well as how it was used after the Jedi were wiped out and Palpatine made it his palace.

Comment: For instance, there is an ancient Sith shrine beneath it, and the Jedi didn't know about it.  According to the book *Tarkin*, part of the reason the Jedi fell was because the dark side power lingering in the Sith shrine seeped up into the Jedi temple and weakened them.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114254/do-the-jedi-and-sith-temples-lie-along-or-at-points-of-concentrated-force?rq=1

Comment: Are you also interested in non canon parts? then there COULD be something in an upcoming rpg book (nexus of power) from fantasy flight game there

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Yes

Here are various cut-aways of the Jedi temple on Coruscant from *Inside the Worlds of Star Wars: Episode I*.  The lower right corner has blueprints (click to enlarge):

[image]

For blueprints with more detail and from a different angle, artist Jeffrey Scott made his own version:

[image]

(Artist page [here](http://jeffrey-scott.deviantart.com/art/Jedi-Temple-Cross-Section-redo-157883736))

This is fan-made, but based on information from the book *Star Wars: Complete Locations*.

Comment: I thought the Jedi High Council met at the top of the center spire? The fan drawing has it in one of the four smaller ones.

Comment: @iMerchant : It was originally in the smaller southwestern tower --- see the blurbs in the top image.  :-)

Comment: Why can't we have such nice things for Episode IV-b?

Comment: They'll need to update the schematic to reflect the fact that *Tarkin* introduced the new idea that the Temple is located atop an ancient Sith Shrine, which helped weaken the Jedi Order over time.  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114254/do-the-jedi-and-sith-temples-lie-along-or-at-points-of-concentrated-force?rq=1

Comment: Y'know, those aren't blueprints; That's a planometic drawing and a perspective, and the fan drawing's a cutaway elevation. Blueprinting technology's been embarrassingly obsolete for some time. Also they're the wrong colour.

Comment: @user867 : There is a *blue* version of the fan drawing, for what it's worth. :-)